# Auto fill the MultiCheckbox on back-end

Tags: checkbox, zend-framework2

I am creating an application on zend2 and I would like to get help.
I want to automatically fill some checkboxes in the backend.

The method `getMessages()` returns the following array:

```php
array(
    'info' => 'INFO',
    'alert' => 'ALERT',
    'more' => 'MORE'
);
```

Form creation

```php
$msg = array(); //  my array
foreach ($this->getMessages() as $key => $value) {

    if(in_array($key, $user_values)) {
        $msg[$key][1] = 'user';
    }
    if(in_array($key, $admin_values)){
        $msg[$key][2] = 'admin';
    }
    if(!in_array($key, $user_values) && !in_array($key, $admin_values)){
        $msg[$key][] = 'skip';
    }

    $form->get(trim($key))->setValueOptions(array($msg))->setChecked(true);
    // OR
    $form->get(trim($key))->setValue(array($msg))->setChecked(true);

    // Clear the array
    $msg = array();
}
```

The result I'd like to obtain:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="alert[]" value="skip' />
<input type="checkbox" name="alert[]" value="user' />
<input type="checkbox" name="alert[]" value="admin' />
```

Comment: All checkbox (multicheckbox) are unchecked !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setValue()` method to set the value that shoud be selected (or checked). You can also use `setAttribute('selected', 'selected')` eventually.

Comment: Thanks, i have to clear the array's values whitespace and $form->get(trim($key))->setValue($value_or_array_value)) (all data come from a file.conf). Resolved !!!